# Grep to find the correct line, sed to change the contents, then putting it back into the original file?

Tags: sed, grep, variable-substitution

I'm trying to change a single word on a specific line in a file, but I'm having some trouble connecting all together.

Basically, on one line in my file there is a keyword 'firmware_revision', and on this line (and only this line) I want to replace the word 'test' with the word 'production'.

So I can do this:

```
grep 'firmware_revision' myfile.py | sed 's/test/production'
```

This will pick out the line I want and perform the substitution, but I can't figure out how to get this new line into the original file to replace the old line. I obviously cannot just redirect it back to the file, so what should I do?

Even if I use temporaries, by using `grep` to get just the line I need I lose all of the other data in the file, so I can no longer just redirect it all to a temp file then replace the original with the temp.

Edit - Someone asked for more information

Lets say I have a file full of lines like this

```
[
  ('key_name1', str, 'value1', 'Description'),
  ('key_name2', str, 'value2', 'Description'),
  ('key_name3', str, 'value3', 'Description'),
  ('firmware_revision', str, 'my-firmware-name-test', 'Firmware revision name')
]
```

now I want to write a script (ideally a one-liner) that will find the line that contains 'firmware_revision', and changes all instances of the word 'test' on that line to 'production'. The word 'test' might be in other places in that file and I do not want those changed. So to be clear, I want to change the above line to

`('firmware_revision', str, 'my-firmware-name-production', 'Firmware revision name')`

How do I do this?

Comment: `sed` is very powerful, it can perform both functions (`grep` and substitution) but we will need more info on how the line looks to help you.

Comment: I'll add more information to the original post

Comment: Try: `sed -i.bak  '/firmware_revision/ s/test/production/' myfile.py`

Comment: Ah it worked perfectly! Can you explain the syntax?

Comment: @JohnAllard Very good.  I added an answer with explanation.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try:

```
sed -i.bak '/firmware_revision/ s/test/production/' myfile.py
```

Here, `/firmware_revision/` acts as a condition.  It is true for lines that match the regex `firmware_revision` and false for other lines.  If the condition is true, then the command which follows is executed.  In this case, that command is a substitute command that replaces the first occurrence of `test` with `production`.

In other words, the command `s/test/production/` is executed only on lines which match the regex `firmware_revision`.  All other lines pass through unchanged.

By default, sed sends its output to standard out.  You, however, wanted to change the file in place.  So, we added the `-i` option.  In particular, `-i.bak` causes the file to be changed in place with a back-up copy saved with a `.bak` extension.

If you have decided that the command works for you and you want to live dangerously and not create a backup, then, with GNU sed (Linux), use:

```
sed -i '/firmware_revision/ s/test/production/' myfile.py
```

By contrast, on BSD (OSX), the `-i` option must have an argument.  If you don't want to keep a backup, provide it with an empty argument.  Thus, use:

```
sed -i '' '/firmware_revision/ s/test/production/' myfile.py
```

#### Edit

In the edit to the question, the OP asks for *every* occurrence of `test` on the line to be replaced with `production`.  In that case, we add the `g` option to the substitute command for a *global* (for that line) replacement:

```
sed -i.bak '/firmware_revision/ s/test/production/g' myfile.py
```

Comment: For completeness, you may wish to explain the `-i.bak` part as well.

Comment: @StephenHarris Good point.  Explanation of `-i` added.

Comment: I feel you could probably reach the stars, just standing on the book explaining all the things that `sed` can do...

Comment: @John1024 For the not BSD people, could you add the reasons of the first  `''` after `-i` ?

Comment: OP wanted to **changes all instances of the word 'test' on that line to 'production'**. It's important to append /g to the sed command in this case:
`sed -i '/firmware_revision/ s/test/production/g' myfile.py`, otherwise only the *first* instance is changed.

Comment: @Hastur I updated the answer with a discussion of that.  In brief, for GNU, the argument to `-i` is optional.  On BSD, it is required.  For the special case of an empty argument, as in `-i ""`, BSD sed does not save a backup file.

Comment: @John1024 Thanks I use to forget it...

Answer (score 4):

On older machines with old-school `sed` that doesn't support option `-i`:

```bash
TF=$( mktemp -t "${0##*/}"_$$_XXXXXXXX ) && \
trap 'rm -f "$TF"' EXIT HUP INT QUIT TERM && \
sed '/firmware_revision/ s/test/production/' myfile.py >"$TF" && \
mv -f "$TF" myfile.py
```

Comment: On those older machines you can simply use `ed` and do it in one line: `printf %s\\n g/firmware_revision/s/test/production/g w q | ed -s myfile.py`

Comment: @don_crissti Very true that, but `ed(1)` doesn't offer any pretext to show the use of `mktemp(1)`.

Comment: If you're using a tempfile, you may as well keep the inode and perms of the original file, same as `ed` does.  Instead of `mv -f "$TF" myfile.pl`, use `cat "$TF" > myfile.pl && rm -f "$TF"`.  BTW, it's good practice to use lowercase variable names (`$tf` instead of `$TF`), they're guaranteed not to conflict with any bash built-in vars (probably other bourne shells too).

Comment: @cas Re: `cat "$TF" > myfile.pl`: try this: `touch a b; chmod 0444 a; cat b >a` (BTW, `sed -i` won't work in that case, either).   Better let the user deal with that.  Re: `rm -f "$TF"`: not needed, see `trap ... EXIT`.  Re: `$tf` instead of `$TF`: maybe; it's a matter of style.

Comment: That's normal and expected behaviour of unix file permissions.  My point was that creating a new file and mv-ing it over the original will 1. result in a new inode for that filename (breaking any hard-links).  2. possibly change perms, if current `umask`  differs from original perms.   As for uppercase vars, it's not just a matter of style - lots of people who have made the mistake of using uppercase PATH or RANDOM or SHELL or whatever for their own variables have found out the hard way.  (and yes, i often use uppercase vars myself.  I know it's wrong, I'm trying to break the habit).